# What is "utility" in Solaris when referred to by the Solaris section of Oracle's CPU?

Tags: security, solaris

Within the Oracle CPU (Patch information) on Solaris some patches are referred to and reflect "Oracle Systems (component: Utility)."

You can see it here referred to also in the CVE information in various websites such as:

https://www.cvedetails.com/cve-details.php?t=1&cve_id=CVE-2022-21416

However, does anyone know what it is? If it said "Filesystem" or "Kernel" then that is obvious. This is very strange. Can anyone explain or guess what might be meant?

I have been through all of the documentation here:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/solaris.html

Yet the meaning of what "Utility" is remains unclear.

Comment: Tools like `ls`, `ps`, `format`.....

Comment: Thanks @RomeoNinov I did consider that, but I feel like that just can't be it?... Can it...? almost EVERYTHING that can be used at the command line then, becomes a "utility" scp, pkgadd, pretty much everything. And if it was a security problem with a utility of this nature, surely the patch details would be more specific I feel.

Comment: Your system will not be w/o kernel/network/services. But can live w/o `prstat` for example. Maybe this is the reason Oracle/Sun name them utilities :)

Comment: Given what has been disclosed in the CVE details, do you perhaps have any insight at all as to how this exploit might work @RomeoNinov ?

Comment: No idea, sorry. Currently I do not work actively with Solaris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It generally refers to a command-line utility or program.  The component listed is the component type field from Oracle's internal bug database for Solaris, and common values are:

```
CONFIG     - Configuration files and issues (not tools)
CPU-MOD    - Kernel & library modules to support specific CPUs
DATABASE   - Database software bundled in the OS
DOC        - Documentation, other than man pages
DRIVER     - Drivers for hardware devices
FILESYSTEM - Filesystems
G11N       - Globalization (i18n/l10n)
JAVA-CLASS - Java classes, other than JDK/JRE bundled
KERNEL     - Kernel, other than drivers & filesystems
LIBRARY    - Libraries
PERL-MOD   - Perl modules, other than the core set
PYTHON-MOD - Python modules, other than the core set
SERVICE    - Services and daemons
UTILITY    - Utility commands and programs
```